# Import EXCEL with SSIS without knowing sheename

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm trying to use SSIS to import multiple files from a folder, and i dont know the `SheetName`.

So, I'm creating a script task according to below link, to get `SheetName`,  but i got error in the script task 'array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration'

http://www.anupamanatarajan.com/2011/01/dynamic-sheet-name-in-ssis-excel.html

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here


            string excelFile = null;
            string connectionString = null;
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = null;
            DataTable tablesInFile = null;
            int tableCount = 0;
            DataRow tableInFile = null;
            string currentTable = null;
            int tableIndex = 0;
            string[] excelTables = null;



            excelFile = Dts.Variables["User::BBGFilePath"].Value.ToString();

            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";

            excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            excelConnection.Open();
            tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

            tableCount = tablesInFile.Rows.Count;
            excelTables = new string[tableCount];

            foreach (DataRow tableInFile_loopVariable in tablesInFile.Rows)
            {
                tableInFile = tableInFile_loopVariable;
                currentTable = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                excelTables[tableIndex] = currentTable;
                tableIndex += 1;
            }
        }

            //Provide value to the shetename variable
            Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value = excelTables[0];



            //Display file name
            string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::BBGFilePath"].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(strMessage);


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

So i tried to add the `[User:SheetName]` variable to the `Script task`, but it doesn't work.

can anyone please check what is missing?

[image]

Comment: Share your script task code here, the error you posted means that you have some non-declaration statements at the class level which is not valid.

Comment: If there is more than one sheet, how will you decide which one to import? You can write much simpler code than what is posted. The first step is to reproduce the code in your question and indicate which line the error occurs on

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid There is usually only one sheet, but multiple files and sheetname is not always the same, so i just take the first sheet (which might be wrong sometimes i guess but i dont see a better way). I have posted the code above. error happens only on the line 'Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value = excelTables[0];'. I didn't set variable for '["User::BBGFilePath"]' in the code either but there is no error with that.

Comment: @Abhishek, thank you. I have added code above

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean in this case?   If you get an error, what is the error message?

Comment: @TabAlleman same error message as the beginning ''array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration''

Comment: If you step through the code in the debugger, what line does the error occur on?

Comment: @TabAlleman error happens only on the line 'Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value = excelTables[0];'. I didn't set variable for '["User::BBGFilePath"]' in the code either but there is no error with that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had mentioned earlier, the error does clearly suggested you have some non-declaration statements at the class level which is not valid.

Your code from the script task have some issues with the closing brace --

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            string excelFile = null;
            string connectionString = null;
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = null;
            DataTable tablesInFile = null;
            int tableCount = 0;
            DataRow tableInFile = null;
            string currentTable = null;
            int tableIndex = 0;
            string[] excelTables = null;

            excelFile = Dts.Variables["User::BBGFilePath"].Value.ToString();

            //Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\CESLtd\ELKAY\Reports\Work2\Book1.xls; Extended Properties = "EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES";
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";

            excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            excelConnection.Open();
            tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

            tableCount = tablesInFile.Rows.Count;
            excelTables = new string[tableCount];

            foreach (DataRow tableInFile_loopVariable in tablesInFile.Rows)
            {
                tableInFile = tableInFile_loopVariable;
                currentTable = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                excelTables[tableIndex] = currentTable;
                tableIndex += 1;
            }
        //} **commented this line now you are good to go**

            //Provide value to the shetename variable
            Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value = excelTables[0];



            //Display file name
            string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::BBGFilePath"].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(strMessage);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        }
```