# RUNTIME ERROR in SSIS when trying to display excel sheetname

Tags: excel, ssis

I try to use SSIS to get sheet name of excel because the sheet name is unknown. But I get some error.

Can someone please check? I tried to google but don't find solution that is applied to my case...

[image]

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Here is my code:

```
public void Main() {
    string excelFile = null;
    string connectionString = null;
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = null;
    DataTable tablesInFile = null;
    int tableCount = 0;
    DataRow tableInFile = null;
    string currentTable = null;
    int tableIndex = 0;
    string[] excelTables = null;

    excelFile = Dts.Variables["User::BBGFilePath"].Value.ToString();
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
     excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
     excelConnection.Open();
     tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
     tableCount = tablesInFile.Rows.Count;
     excelTables = new string[tableCount];

     foreach (DataRow tableInFile_loopVariable in tablesInFile.Rows) {
         tableInFile = tableInFile_loopVariable;
         currentTable = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
         excelTables[tableIndex] = currentTable;
         tableIndex += 1;
     }

     Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value = excelTables[0];
     string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
     MessageBox.Show(strMessage);
     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: Why did you accept this answer here if it throws an error?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810486/import-excel-with-ssis-without-knowing-sheename. And again: what line does this occur on?

Comment: What changes did you do, this is a different error all together from the last one.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid because its a new error and i wanted to respected the answer in previous thread.

Comment: @Abhishek, the difference is i added below lines to display sheetname:string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
     MessageBox.Show(strMessage);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now after i changed below:

1. Changed ConnectionString to be :
   ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0\"";
2. There are several places where 'ConnectionString' was written as 'connectionString' and C# seems to be case sensitive? after correcting them it works

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Please do as below

ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";

To display sheet names

> Foreach (var item in execltables) { 
>   Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value = item.tosing();
>        string strMessage = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
>        MessageBox.Show(strMessage);}

Thanks

Comment: thank you. i tried and still got error. now i added a try catch and i can see the error is Systerm.invalidPperatonException: The connectionString property has not been initialized. I added the error screenshot in my thread

Comment: btw i have office 2010 32-bit, and the excel i try to open is .xlsx. Does it make any difference?  I tried ' ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";'    too but still same error